# How to associate training data ID's when using Keras `Model.predict_generator`

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

## Question

I have test data where each example contains a unique `id` as well as a number of features. If I use [Model.predict_generator](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict_generator), then as one of the arguments I pass a generator that loads the data, this will successfully pass along the features of the test data to my model and will spit out predictions. However, I would like to also pass along my `id` property and have the predictions associated with the `id`s. The test data is too big to fit into memory.

## Plausible Solution

I could read the data from the generator directly and instead feed it to [Model.predict](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict). However, this feels like a workaround and I feel that this is something many people have also stumbled into.